# JSON.parse() throws unexpected token error. Don't know why?

Tags: javascript, php, json

PHP

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/json") ;
echo json_encode(array("reply" => "SOME_TEXT")) ;

?>
```

it echos this ->

```
{"reply":"SOME_TEXT"}
```

Javascript

```
<script>
$.get("script.php" , function(data) {
    var reply = JSON.parse(data) ;
}) ;
</script>
```

JS throws `unexpected token in JSON`. But it will working fine if I replace the header in PHP code with **header("Content-type: text/javascript")** or **"text/plain"**.

Comment: Have you verified the JSON payload is valid? https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: If JS throws an error JSON is not valid - there is no reason to not trust it.

Comment: Use console.log("data" + data); to see if your script gets the correct JSON code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery parses the data automatically if the header is set to `application/json`, so you are trying to parse an object. You can use it without `JSON.parse` with the header set to `application/json`:

```
$.get("script.php" , function(data) {
    console.log(data.reply);
}) ;
```

As @charlietft commented,

> using $.getJSON() instead of $.get() will also assure it is parsed

Comment: using `$.getJSON()` instead of `$.get()` will also assure it is parsed and will go to error callbacks if not

Comment: Thanks! @charlietfl